# Custom right click UI Context Menu(copy,paste,cut) For Entire Application (All web pages) Across All Browsers not for single web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to develop a Custom ui context menu with simple copy paste options, after searching in google, found a jquery plugin to do same for a html elememt.

Now what i want to know is....? how can i make it applicable to all the web pages in application, not for a individual web page.

any kind of hint will be appreciated
thanks in advance

Edit : I know that i can do this by applying code  in each and every page, is there any  simpler way to do so. using which i can apply the code to entire application at once.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're using the [jQuery-contextMenu](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) plugin, you can simply register a new contextMenu with `body` as a selector:

```
 $.contextMenu({
    selector: 'body'
 });
```

Comment: hi @kristoffer, Am working on Asp.net project, where i have a requirement to use context menu for every page,  if i use above selector it will be applicable to only single page as of my knowledge. my requirement is to apply my context menu for all pages in my asp.net application